# Enable PKCE with Doorkeeper

Tags: doorkeeper

I am trying to enable PKCE with doorkeeper. I've followed the instructions here:

```
https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Using-PKCE-flow
```

Which is basically just run:

```
bundle exec rails generate doorkeeper:pkce
```

However, when I test out the flow I don't see anything getting saved to the new columns that were added to the database from the above command.

I am trying to authorize an app like so:

```
https://my.authserver.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=<client_id>&redirect_uri=<redirect_uri>&scope=<scope>&response_type=code&code_challenge=test&code_challenge_method=plain
```

After I authorize I expect the code_challenge and code_challenge_method to be saved in the db but it isn't.

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out we were overiding the `new.html.erb` and we weren't passing the `code_challenge` and `code_challenge_method` along as hidden form fields.

Comment: YES! Thank you for sharing your solution I had the same problem. I opened https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/guides/pull/8 to get this in the documentation.